# Why does an overriden template class method still get compiled?

Tags: c++

When I create a templated class with a virtual function, and override the function in a derived class, the base function still tries to get compiled.
Here is the minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void Method()
    {
        static_assert(false);
    }
};

class Derived : public Base<int>
{
public:
    void Method() override
    {
        std::cout << "Hello, World!";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived d{};

    d.Method();

    return 0;
}
```

Why does the base method still try to compile when it is overriden?

Comment: `Base<int> b; b.Method();`? Why would you assume the base method _shouldn't_  be compiled?

Comment: This is difficult to avoid in general. If somebody tries to call `Method()` in the constructor/destructor of `Base`, then the base method has to be called, so the pointer to it has to be in the vtable at that moment. If the `Base` had non-trivial constructor/destructor that called functions from other TUs, it wouldn't be possible to check at compile-time if it ultimately calls `Method()` or not. I guess an exception could be added for this specific case, but it's probably not worth it.

Comment: `Derived` inherits `Base`, so a `Derived` *is* a `Base`, so of course all of it needs to compile. And just because you `override` the function doesn't mean you cannot call `Base::Method()`.

Comment: Side note: If not compiled into static libraries or shared objects (on windows DLL) then – if the function is not used – it gets dropped again by the linker. But that's *after* compilation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it needs to be compiled as user can instantiate `Base<T>` and directly call `Method()` on it. If you wanted to make it non-callable, use `virtual void Method() = 0;` for abstract functions.

Second, not only compiled, it's actually accessible from `Derived`: you can call it e.g. from `Derived::Method()`, as `Base<int>::Method()`.

Comment: Those cases you could in theory defer the instantiation of `Method()` until it's called by its qualified name or until `Base<T>` is used as a most-derived object type. It would complicate the rules even more, though.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat As per current rules, if a function is not dependent on a template argument, it's always instantiated. Reason behind, you might need to call it from a derived class (that you don't necessarily know about when you're compiling your code).